# How MeanDecreaseGini is calculated for categorical predictors?

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, random-forest, importance, gini

I'm implementing a random forest algorithm but I noticed that the categorical variable in the database is not selected among the important variables. So I want to know how RF calculates MeanDecreaseGini for the categorical variables that contain more than 2 categories and (2) is it true all the time that the categorical variable has low importance in RF?